# Shiro persist permission - what to save in the DB?

Tags: java, shiro

I have created 3 roles for my application: admin, user, guest. Each of these 3 roles have a set of permissions. I want to persist these roles with their permissions to my database. How do I persist permissions?

```
Role r = new Role("admin");
Permission p1 = new WildcardPermission("Account:Create");
Permission p2 = new WildcardPermission("File:Delete");
r.addPermission(p1);
r.addPermission(p2);
//etc
```

Do I save to my database the following strings "Account:Create" and "File:Delete" and instantialize permission with them when I query the object? If this is the case, why is there no way to get back the original string from the Permission object? If I call p1.toString(), it returns "[Account]:[Create]" which is considered a different permission than "Account:Create".